# Request Item too large OR too many elements

Tags: arrays, iis, request, http-post

When using IIS, I get a 400 error when I scale up the number/size of my .

Originally I thought the problem was the size of the total request object, but I no longer think that is the case.

It 'seems' that what triggers the error is the # of elements in the arrays of data that are in the request object.

Is there a limit that I need to know about regarding the number of elements in an array of data that is contained in the form object?

When I got the error, I backed off on the number of elements in the array until I got the system to pass. Then I took note of the overall size of the request object and 'assumed' that was near the limit. However, I then modified the values withing the array before I did a submit. Initially they are all null, but when I put values in, I can significantly increase the size of the request object without generating an error.

BUT, if I go back to all the data elements being null/empty, and simply add some more elements, then I get the error.

Comment: IIS error 400 occurs when the server was unable to process the request sent to the website server, try using failed request tracing to see details about 400 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tracked it down. The problem doesn't appear to be with IIS but rather with Razor Anti-Forgery functionality. When the number of elements in the form gets too big, the anti-forgery stuff doesn't work. Since this an in-house web application and I'm not concerned about hackers, I turned antiforgery off (`[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]`). Now things work fine.